# How to send sse from a different middleware

Tags: node.js, express, server-sent-events

it's the first time I've come across SSE, and after a while, i finally got something working. The problem is, that wherever I look, there are always the same examples, of a interval or a loop right inside the original middleware, someting like this:

```
app.get('/events', async function(req, res) {
console.log('Got /events');
res.set({
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive'
});
res.flushHeaders();

// Tell the client to retry every 10 seconds if connectivity is lost
res.write('retry: 10000\n\n');
let count = 0;

while (true) {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

  console.log('Emit', ++count);
  // Emit an SSE that contains the current 'count' as a string
  res.write(`data: ${count}\n\n`);
}
```

});

Now this works, but it's not useful. I am building a simple ordering app. I need to send an sse every time someone orders, so you can see the orders in real time. To do this, I need to send the sse messages after an order has been checked and added to the db. I am not only adding the order in a separate middleware, but even in a separate file, and as a response to a different request. I can't just use res.write, as in the example, because it will affect the response to the /add-order request, and not to the /sse. Is there any way I could do this, possibly even without using sse at all? (I am open to using npm packages as well)

Comment: is there any reason not use websockets?? sse are not meant for unidirectional flow packets. websockets will be optimal solution in your case

Comment: well, as far as I read, sse seems to be the unidirectional soluteion, whereas websockets are quote " full-duplex(multiway) communication". It seems as a viable solution, but so did sse before I tried to do it and failed here ^. If I don't find a solution though, I am going for the websockets.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea of SSE remains the same, in your particular case you could use something like the app `EventEmitter`, when an order is created emit the event, while on the other side subscribe to the event, and each time your receive an event send the data over SSE.

Comment: Well, this was a good idea, it's a step forward, the problem is, that i create a listener on the /sse route or request, and when the /add-order request arrives, it doesn't work anymore - it's not the same request, so the event only gets created on the first one, and emitter emits, but there's nothing to catch it.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I mean. You need to create global application level event emitter, then yiu don't really care when and what emitted events.

Comment: Sse side should listen to an event, and send data to a client each time it receives an event, while on add order side you should emit events